# Constructors does not have any return types but then how object is created?

Tags: java, object, constructor

According to the definitions of constructors they don't have any return types,but while creating object we often do  A a = new A(); which is responsible for creating the object a.

```
A a=new A();
```

Can anyone help me understanding the issue,what is actually happening in the case of constructors while creation of Object.

Comment: 'new' creats object, constructor simply sets in up.

Comment: Actually, constructors have return type. What they are missing is a name :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight constructors do not have return types ... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html

Comment: classes are only a definition (and some static refs), "new" keyword creates the objects using the constructor and return a new instance (a reference to the newly created object). Constructor responsibility is put the instance in "working condition", prepare it for future method calls and interaction.

Comment: @LalitMehra The tutorial took one way of fitting the constructor declaration in the `<type> <name> '(' <arguments> ')'` syntax for methods: they say the `<type>` identifier is empty. In my opinion, this fit is inferior to saying that it's the `<name>` identifier that is empty, and the `<type>` identifier matches the type of the class being created.

Answer (score 8):

Constructors don't have return types, correct. But the *expression* `new A()` **does** have a result: A reference to the newly-created object.

Here's what happens with `new A()`:

1. An object is created
2. It's given the type `A`
3. The relevant `A` constructor is called with `this` referring to that new object
4. Once initialization is done, the expression completes
5. The result of the expression is the reference to the new object

This process is described in [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html) on the Oracle Java site.

In many ways, it would be more accurate to call constructors *initializers*: The *construction* happens because of the `new` operator, not the constructor.

The fact that constructors don't actually do the construction is made particularly clear when an object is processed by *multiple* constructors, as is very common. Consider:

```
List<String> m = new LinkedList<String>();
```

**One object** is created (ignoring any fields the list may need to initialize), but **five different constructors** get called to initialize that one object, because `LinkedList<E>` subclasses `java.util.AbstractSequentialList<E>` which subclasses `java.util.AbstractList<E>` which subclasses `java.util.AbstractCollection<E>` which subclasses `java.lang.Object`, and each of those classes has to get its chance to initialize its part of the object that was created. So in order:

- JVM creates the object
- [`Object()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#Object--) is called to initialize `Object` stuff
- [`AbstractCollection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#AbstractCollection--) is called to initialize its stuff
- Then [`AbstractList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#AbstractList--)
- Then [`AbstractSequentialList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html#AbstractSequentialList--)
- Then [`LinkedList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#LinkedList--)
- And then finally the resulting (one) object's reference becomes the result of the `new` expression

One object, but five constructors required to initialize it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html) need not to return anything. They just constructs the current instance. That's all their job, part of object creation.

Comment: But declaring A a and getting the instance actually means that constructor returns something otherwise how instance is being stored inside a ??

Comment: @lucifer You returns the attributes stored in `a` with your `GET` methods that you have created in your object of type `A`.

Answer (score 0):

[Creating objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):

**A a** = new A();

- Declaration: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that associate a variable name with an object type.
- Instantiation: The **new** keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
- Initialization: The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which **initializes the new object**.

> Constructor declarations **look like method declarations**—except
>   that they use the name of the class and have no return type - [from
>   the java constructor docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html)

To understand the constructor, it is similarly important to understand how it differs from a method.

Constructors have one purpose in life: **to initialize the new object and it's fields**. Nothing more. The *new* keyword handles the creation of memory space.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't consider `new A()` to be a call to the constructor, because there are more things that happen, than just the constructor running.  The major steps, when you run `new A()` are these.

1. A chunk of memory is set aside - just enough for storing an object of class `A`.
2. The constructor is run.
3. A reference to the chunk of memory that was set aside is returned.

So the constructor itself isn't actually returning anything - and it's an error to have `return this;` or anything similar inside the constructor.

Comment: @John I would consider that reference to be part of the object.

Comment: But @john how does mentioning one randomly chosen part of the object header make the statement more  correct? David's answer is actually correct as it stands because it subsumes the header under the term "object".

Comment: @Marko Topolnik i wasn't aware that reference to vtable is part of the object header.

Comment: Actually it isn't a pointer to vtable alone but to the complete class structure.

Answer (score 0):

Return statement inside a constructor doesn't logically makes sense because the purpose of the constructor is to perform initialization. The object has not been created yet, the actual construction of the object happens in JVM.